# Azure ARM Custom Extension fileuri from local host

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

In azure ARM Templates I'm trying to execute a script from my local machine in the newly provisioned Azure VM.

The options which I see till now are git and azure storage.

My question is: is there a way to execute the file from local machine

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way of doing that with custom script extension. You can use `Invoke-AzVmRunCommand` or `az vm run-command`. They are designed specifically for that

Comment: really thanks for this, really was searching for this .. do you have a guide for creating these templates

Comment: i dont think you can use that from the templates, since its a local script, it doesnt make sense

Comment: @4c74356b41 How can that be done from the template? I just basically want to run a script which is available in the virtual machine, in the custom script extension

Comment: create a new question or google it, this is a completely different question. in short - specify the path to the script in the script extension